# How to subscribe to given thread in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

Despite my best efforts I don't see such action. I googled and I see some posts from around 2011 about this feature, but since then the UI changed, however I hope this feature is still somewhere.

So, how to do it? Not entire group, just selected threads.

*For the record I am looking at [Haxe group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haxelang).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open any individial topic. 
Press the tiny downward 'Topic Options' arrow, located
just below the topic title, between 'x posts by y authors' 
and the G+ button. Select 'email updates to me' .

Later, visit 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsubscriptions/haxelang

Comment: Seems like this option is not available anymore.

Comment: The option is gone, but under "My Settings" you can still select "My topic email subscriptions". For me none appear - either I have none, or this no longer works. Just another perplexing Google feature deletion.